# fill=TRUE will fail when different number of column occurr after 5 rows in read.table?

Tags: r, read.table

Let's say we have a file name `test.txt` which contains unknown number of columns:

```
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

`fill=T` fails when line 8 has more than 5 columns:

```
read.table('test.txt', header=F, sep='\t', fill=T)
```

results:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1   1  2  3  4  5
2   1  2  3  4  5
3   1  2  3  4  5
4   1  2  3  4  5
5   1  2  3  4  5
6   1  2  3  4  5
7   1  2  3  4  5
8   1  2  3  4  5
9   6  7  8 NA NA
10  1  2  3  4  5
11  1  2  3  4  5
12  6 NA NA NA NA
13  1  2  3  4  5
14  6 NA NA NA NA
15  1  2  3  4  5
16  6 NA NA NA NA
```

But with `skip=3`, everything works fine

```
read.table('test.txt', header=F, sep='\t', fill=T, skip=3)
```

We got what we expected:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA
2  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA
3  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA
4  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA
5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
6  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA NA
7  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA
8  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA
9  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA NA
```

Why would this happen? Was it because `fill=T` only check the first 5 rows? Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: According to `?read.table` `The number of data columns is determined by looking at the first
     five lines of input (or the whole file if it has less than five
     lines), or from the length of ‘col.names’ if it is specified and
     is longer.  This could conceivably be wrong if ‘fill’ or
     ‘blank.lines.skip’ are true, so specify ‘col.names’ if necessary
     (as in the ‘Examples’).`

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. I've found the anwser right in the Examples.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the answers right in the Examples of read.table.

```
ncol <- max(count.fields('test.txt', sep = "\t"))
read.table('test.txt', header=F, sep='\t', fill=T, col.names=paste0('V', seq_len(ncol)))
```

It did because of `fill=T` only checks the first five rows. The solution is to specify `col.names`.

Answer (score 2):

use `col.names = paste0("V",seq_len(N))` within `read.table` where `N` is the maximum number of columns.