# Read comma separated string data from csv file into list in R

Tags: text-mining

I have a csv file with data on grouping of cereal brands in an experiment. I have one row for each subject (~2000 subjects) and each row has a variable number of brand that people liked (text strings separated by commas)

srno   Brands
1     GMI 'TOTAL' WG ORIG,POS H-C GRAPE NUTS ORIG,POST GREAT GRAINS CRUNCHY PCN
2     GMI TINY TST STB,GMI HONEY NUT CHEERIOS REG,GMI TINY TST BB,GMI APPLE CN TOAST CRUNCH
3     QKR SQUARES CN

I want to read the data into a data frame so that I have the brands in each row as one element of a list
My goal is to be able to do a text mining analysis to explore similarities (ie brands that occur together)

I see a similar question asked a few years ago but I was not able to adapt the solution
[Text file to list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602881/text-file-to-list-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work this out!
I read in the csv file with StringsAsFactors=FALSE option (this is important)

```
`x = read.csv ("datafile.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)        
#strings of brand names read into variable str_brand        
#the following stmt then turns the chars in str_brand into a list         
#note..I had the individual brands separated by commas in the csv file
```

brands_list <- stringr::str_split(x$str_brand,pattern = ",")

`