# Importing list from capture.output() into R

Tags: r

If we have a list in R and want to export it, [the simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594541/export-a-list-into-a-csv-or-txt-file-in-r) is to use:

`capture.output(mylist, file = "NewFile.txt")`

How do we then re-import the file "NewFile.txt" back into R as a list?

Comment: You may save as .Rdata and load. Or as `.rds` with `saveRDS/readRDS`

Comment: How long is your list, roughly? Do you just need to save it and import it back into R, or will some other program use it? Does it have to be txt, or can you use a binary format like RDS, as suggested above?

Comment: will quickly help you out, taking into account the comments that have been put accross. do `save(mylist, file = 'NewFile')` to save the work, then to use the list aggain, do `load('NewFile')`

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602881/text-file-to-list-in-r