# Import data in the format of a list into R

Tags: r, import

I have several text files that stores list data  (from a output of a model) like this.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "gender"           "n_sum"           "delq"        "i_sum"          
[5] "bf_mj"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "gender"    "n_sum"    "delq" "c_sum"    "e_sum"    "race_bin" 

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "gende"            "delq"         "e_sum"           
[4] "race"          "parnt_edu"  "bf_alc"

[[1]][[4]]
character(0)
```

Is there a way to import these kind of text files into R?. I tried `read.csv` and `read.table`. But it didn't work.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How did you get the data above? Perhaps [text file to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602881/text-file-to-list-in-r).

Comment: In the future, do not save lists as text files, use `saveRDS()` or `save()`. This is especially true if any of the values are numeric since printing a list generally loses numeric precision.